# Problems with Pelican control using asctec_drivers

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
We recently got the Pelican quadrotor, and I am trying to figure out how to interact with.

I tried playign with the ros asctec_drivers and I was confused about a few things:

1. when i run the asctec drivers using the command: roslaunch asctec_proc asctec_driver.launch
   although i do get the quadrotor status in the asctec_mon node, however I get neverending stream of error messages also which look like this:

   ```
    ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

    core service [/rosout] found
    process[AutoPilot-1]: started with pid [8567]
    process[AsctecProc-2]: started with pid [8575]
    [ INFO] [1310403092.428431980]: Creating AutoPilot Interface
    [ INFO] [1310403092.467485696]: Initializing serial port...
    [ INFO] [1310403092.467751836]: Starting AsctecProc
    [ INFO] [1310403092.480610254]: Successfully connected to /dev/ttyUSB0, Baudrate 57600

    [ INFO] [1310403092.482211992]: Publishing LL_STATUS data
    [ INFO] [1310403092.483186079]: Publishing IMU_CALCDATA data
    [ INFO] [1310403092.483218031]: Control Disabled
    [ERROR] [1310403092.795496644]:   Unexpected Data: Flushing receive buffer
    [ERROR] [1310403092.808786791]:     Error Reading Packet Header: Resource temporarily unavailable
    [ERROR] [1310403092.808928489]:     Read (3): ;?
    [ERROR] [1310403092.809003484]:   Read failed
    [ERROR] [1310403092.835423407]:     Error Reading Packet Header: Resource temporarily unavailable
    [ERROR] [1310403092.835498263]:     Read (3): ??
    [ERROR] [1310403092.835534067]:   Read failed
    [ERROR] [1310403092.933538751]: Timeout: 0 bytes available 3 bytes requested
    [ERROR] [1310403092.954336371]:   Unexpected Data: Flushing receive buffer
    [ERROR] [1310403092.964756981]:     Error Reading Packet Header: Resource temporarily unavailable
    [ERROR] [1310403092.964830510]:     Read (3): 
    [ERROR] [1310403092.964864269]:   Read failed
    ..
    ..
    ..
   ```

does anyone know what is causing it?

2. How can I send waypoints to the pelican using this ros stack? I do not see any topics for it.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10563/problems-with-pelican-control-using-asctec_drivers/) by [Yogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105/yogi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 411 on 2011-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

yogi found a (at least partial) solution [here](http://asctec-users.986163.n3.nabble.com/ros-asctec-drivers-stack-td3159818.html#none)

For the waypoints, do you want to send GPS waypoints, or do you want to navigate the pelican based on some laser/camera slam or odometry? For the latter case, if you can provide position and yaw, you can have a look [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/asctec_mav_framework).

---

Originally posted by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) with karma: 390 on 2011-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) on 2011-08-11**:
An explanation / solution is now posted here: http://asctec-users.986163.n3.nabble.com/Mysterious-packet-0x31-td3166386.html